# Swift try with question mark

Tags: swift, exception, syntax, try-catch

I see the following in the code maintained by me:

```
func parse(values: NSMutableDicationary) {
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
}
```

Pay attention that the method does not mark as throwing anything nor does it handle the error. The code does crash the application though.

I am trying to figure out what does `try?` (try with a question mark) means.

Googling or StackOverflowing did not return any useful info.

So, what does `try?` mean in Swift?

Comment: Look for `Converting Errors to Optional Values` in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html "The code does crash the application though": Is values nil? If that's the case, I don't think that the error is catchable this way, so the "try?" won't do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part in the documentation.

Comment: Open "The Swift Programming Language" in iBooks, enter command-F for "Find" and "try?" in the search field. Then you'll find the answer immediately.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you mark a `try` with a question mark as `try?`, the return value of the throwable function will be optional. It will be `nil` in case the function threw an error (so Swift returns a `nil` instead of throwing the error, hence you don't need a `do-catch` block) or it will be the wrapped return value of the function in case no error was thrown.

This is how you can mimic the behaviour in your own function:

```
func parse(values: NSMutableDicationary)->Data?{
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
func parse(values: NSMutableDicationary)->Data?{
    return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
}
```

Comment: Definitely makes sense. Thank you for a quick answer and I have no idea how I missed Apple's docs about it.

Answer (score 2):

From apple documentation, try? handles an error by converting it to an optional value. If an error is thrown while evaluating the try? expression, the value of the expression is nil.

So the result is one of two:

A. there is error thrown and `data` is nil, and trying to use the data variable is what causing the crash

B. the thrown error is not catched by `try?` which happens a lot in functions that run async for some reason

Answer (score 2):

**try?**

It returns an optional that unwraps successful values, and catches error by returning nil. Use `try?` when you’re try to discover only with `true` and `false`

Using `try?` you can't except why(reason) this gonna failed.

```
func parse(values: NSMutableDicationary) {

    //It return only exacat value Data or nil.
    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) {
        //Perform operation with data
    }
}
```